# How can I intercept mouse events outside a Java modal dialog,

Tags: java, swing, dialog, awt, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog in Java and want to know when the user clicks outside the dialog (on another window in the application) instead of just having it go "blong" and flash the border. For such things as picking a color etc etc.

Answer (score 5):

Make the dialog non-modal and you can still interact with the rest of the application.

Comment: True unless like i my case I want to intercecpt the events before they get to and activate the other application widows.  That is without installing a filter on every component in the application or putting a filter on the AWT event queue.

Comment: What is it exactly the GUI **should** do, if you could achieve your aim?  Nothing?  Providing no visual or audio feedback to the end user would make for an unusable GUI.  Can you name (link to) any (free) app. that supports the feature you wish to implement?